A curious case of combinational logic
I am running circles around the following scenario and have no idea of where the solution will be. The task is to implement the following gray to binary converter in SystemVerilog:

I adapted a Verilog example from the book: "Learning by Example Using Verilog":
module gray2bin
#(parameter bits=3)
(
    input logic [bits-1:0] g,
    output logic [bits-1:0] b
);

integer i;

always_comb
begin
    b[bits-1] = g[bits-1];
    for(i=bits-2; i>=0; i--)
    begin: conversion
        b[i] = b[i+1] ^ g[i];
    end
end

endmodule:gray2bin

Simulation shows that this module works as intended, but I thought of a shorter way of expressing the same thing, by substituting the for loop with continuous assignments, like so:
assign b[bits-1] = g[bits-1];
assign b[bits-2:0] = b[bits-1:1] ^ g[bits-2:0];

This doesn't work in simulation, specifically when I assign the first value in the work bench, an all zeroes input: g = 3'b000, the simulation returns this value: b = 3'b00x.  Needless to say, could not figure out why this is happening, so I moved the continuous assignments to an always_comb hoping that the sequential nature of it will solve this problem:
always_comb
begin
    b[bits-1] = g[bits-1];
    b[bits-2:0] = b[bits-1:1] ^ g[bits-2:0];
end

But, I got the same behavior, which is strange.  The RTL viewer shows the same implementation for the three versions of the module, so, why just only one of them works?  Maybe I am hitting some simulator quarks?  Any insight will be greatly appreciated.
My set-up is:

Synthesis tool: Quartus Prime Version 23.1.std.0 Build 991 11/28/2023 SC Lite Edition.
Simulation tool: Questa Intel Starter FPGA Edition-64 2023.3.


It's true that begin/end blocks execute code inside them sequentially. Here sequentially means in serial order, not necessarily sequential logic. Multiple blocking assignments to the same variable (or the same select of of a variable) are treated like assignments to intermediate variables. Only the last assignment to a variable is what get updated. Last is determinate because of the serial ordering.
When you write these out as continuous assignments, you lose the intermediate variables and you run into a different problem with sensitivity with the same bits appearing on the RHS and LHS of the assignments. This gives you indeterminate simulation results that a synthesis tool would not have a problem with.

quick follow up @dave_59, if I could implement this physically, would I get the expected behavior? Or will it also fail in an FPGA or VLSI implementation?

Some synthesis tools will allow you to model code that synthesises into logic that would not simulate correctly, others will generate an error.

Thanks @dave_59, this is new information to me :)

Using the assign is shorter than the for loop, but it is not the same thing.  This is why it simulates differently.
The statements in the for code are assigned in sequence, whereas the statements in the two assign lines are in parallel.
It is easier to understand if you mentally unroll the for loop. In this case, you have 3 assignments that happen one after the other (not in parallel):
b[2] = g[2];
b[1] = b[2] ^ g[1];
b[0] = b[1] ^ g[0];

b[1] relies on the new value of b[2].  b[0] relies on the new value of b[1].

but even if done in parallel (in the as in the assign statements) shouldn't it be the same thing? the RTL generated by every version is exactly the same, just a bunch of XOR gates, still baffles me.

@JacobMoralesGonzalez: Since you accepted an answer, I assume you are no longer baffled.
